Is the Galois closure of a $p$-adic Lie group extension also a $p$-adic Lie group extension?
Let $p$ be a prime. Let $K$ be a number field and $L/K$ be an infinite extension which is not necessarily Galois. Suppose that the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ of $L/K$ is $p$-adic analytic, i.e. it is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of $ \operatorname{GL}_{d}(\mathbb{Z}_{p}) $ for some positive integer $ d $ where $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers. Let $M$ denote the Galois closure of $L/K$. Is the Galois group $\text{Gal}(M/K)$ of $M/K$ also $p$-adic analytic?

Take any infinite extension such that $Aut(L / K)$ is trivial (these exist). Then the condition is satisfied for all $p$ at once, but $Gal(M / K)$ is an infinite pro-finite group so it can't be $p$-adic analytic for several $p$ simultaneously.
